# Android ConstraintLayout alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `ConstraintLayout` to build my UI it works great on my phone but on other phone the button is place at the corner and not in place, I configure everything in the SDK tools, like its mention in Android developers but with no suc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    tools:context="com.example.amit.who.MainActivity">

    <!-- Play button-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:onClick="startGame"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.49"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_play" />
    <!-- Open information button-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:onClick="openInstructions"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/instruction_icon" />
    <!-- Sound\Mute button-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:onClick="toggleMute"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/unmute" />
    <!-- Choosing character-->
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="307dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!-- Fiction-->
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/fiction"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:scaleX="0.85"
            android:scaleY="0.85" />
        <!-- Nonfiction-->
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/non_fiction" />
        <!-- Mixed-->
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/mixed" />

    </RadioGroup>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml to show what constraints you have set.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's wrong if you don't tell us which View is the problem?

Comment: everyone, they all placed in the corners

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of how do you want it will look?